# Numpy generate array from csv - doesnt work with only 1 value in csv

Tags: arrays, csv, python-3.x, numpy

I have a problem with importing a csv using numpy, it works fine when there are more than 1 values in the csv, e.g. "one,two,three" but if I have just one value in the csv it won't work - "one"

My code below fails when iterating through terms:

```
import numpy as np

global file_path
global terms
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

terms = np.genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter=",", dtype=str)

for t in terms:
    mydict[t.lower().lstrip()] = False
```

- TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

Can anyone advise on how be able to iterate through an array with 1 item?

Comment: Can you show us the first few lines of your file?

Comment: added the first lines, the t in terms part runs from a tkinter button click function but I removed that so it didn't confuse matters

Comment: Can you show us `terms`? ... I could imagine that it is not a list if there is only one value in the csv

Comment: That's my problem - as csv with - one,two,three - works. A csv with - one - doesn't

Comment: If there is no line break  `terms = open(file_path,'r').read().split(',')` should work

Comment: Excellent, thanks. How would I best handle line breaks? Replace with them with commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the nicest code but it should work

```
terms = [x for x in open(file_path,'r').read().replace('\n',',').split(',') if len(x)>0]
```